# Need Menu in Separate html file

Tags: html, menu

I want to create a menu which will be used in 40 to 50 pages. I want to create it in a separate file so that it can be updated easily. How to do that?

Comment: Which server side language are you using ?

Comment: @Roopendra its javascript

Comment: Does below solutions resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Put your menu HTML somewhere and use jQuery to load it into a designated element:

```
$("#menu").load( "menu.html" );
```

Comment: isn't this bad for SEO?

Answer (score 0):

Okay there a 3 ways:

1. PHP. Include it per PHP (include Command)
2. JavaScript. Load it with AJAX and display it in a div. (jQuery will help you)
3. Iframe. Dirty and ugly but it will be the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

To put a menu (or any other HTML section) in a separate file wihout jquery or iframes you can use Server Side Includes (SSI).

1. Create a single HTML file containing the HTML you want to include, eg the HTML of a menu that needs to be repeated in many files. Do *not* includ `<! doctype`,  `<head>` etc. Save the file with a `.shtml` extension, eg `menu.shtml` (alough usually it works with just .html). Example:

   ```
   <ul id="navmenu">
   <li><a href="page1.shtml">Page One</a></li>
   <li><a href="page2.shtml">Page Two</a></li>
   <li><a href="page3.shtml">Page Three</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Add the include statement to every file you want this menu to be put in:

   ```
    <!-- #include file="menu.shtml" -->
   ```

Paths are relative, using a path relative to the root of the webserver is done by:.

```
<!--#include virtual="/directory/menu.shtml" -->
```

[More info](http://mobile.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341)

[Info on SSI with php, VBScript and other languages](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/creating-a-headerfooter-to-be-used-on-all-pages/)